# How to inject a formatted paragraph into a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, textblock, paragraph

I'm trying to transmit the formatted content of a paragraph to a TextBlock, but the formatting disappears:

```
// Create a formatted paragraph
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.FontSize = 25;
para.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("Text of paragraph."));

// Create a span with the content of the paragraph (FontSize 25 and FontWeight Bold stay alive)
Span span = new Span(para.ContentStart, para.ContentEnd);

// Create a TextBlock with the span (FontSize 25 and FontWeight Bold get lost)
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.Add(span);
```

What could be done to keep the formatting? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
The formatting of the paragraph is known at runtime, so I can't apply property values one by one manually.

**Update 2**
The background of the question is that I want to measure the length of formatted paragraphs if they are stretched to one line. 
This can be done by a TextBlock. The paragraphs are located in TableCells, I want to adjust the column widths automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached the following solution:

```
// Create a formatted Paragraph
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.FontSize = 25;
para.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("Text of paragraph."));

// Clone all Inlines
List<Inline> clonedInlines = new List<Inline>();
foreach (Inline inline in para.Inlines)
{
    Inline clonedInline = ElementClone<Inline>(inline);
    clonedInlines.Add(clonedInline);
}

// Get all Paragraph properties with a set value
List<DependencyProperty> depProps = DepPropsGet(para, PropertyFilterOptions.SetValues);

// Apply the Paragraph values to each Inline
foreach (DependencyProperty depProp in depProps)
{
    object propValue = para.GetValue(depProp);

    foreach (Inline clonedInline in clonedInlines)
    {
        // Can the Inline have the value?
        if (depProp.OwnerType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Inline)))
        {
            // Apply the Paragraph value
            clonedInline.SetValue(depProp, propValue);
        }
    }
}

// Create a TextBlock with the same properties as the Paragraph
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(clonedInlines);

/// <summary>
/// Cloner.
/// </summary>
public static T ElementClone<T>(T element)
{
    // Element to Stream
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    XamlWriter.Save(element, memStream);

    // Cloned element from Stream
    object clonedElement = null;
    if (memStream.CanRead)
    {
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        clonedElement = XamlReader.Load(memStream);
        memStream.Close();
    }
    return (T)clonedElement;
}

/// <summary>
/// Property-Getter.
/// </summary>
public static List<DependencyProperty> DepPropsGet(DependencyObject depObj, PropertyFilterOptions filter)
{
    List<DependencyProperty> result = new List<DependencyProperty>();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(depObj, new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(filter) }))
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);

        if (dpd != null)
        {
            result.Add(dpd.DependencyProperty);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting cannot be applied to the `TextBlock`, it is similar to a `Label`, if you need formating then you can use [`<RichTextBox/>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. you can make it `ReadOnly` to avoid editing.

Example:

```
   <RichTextBox Margin="10" ReadOnly="true">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="36">Hello, world!</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray">Thanks to the RichTextBox control, this FlowDocument is completely editable!</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I had to use `IsReadOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what @un-lucky says, TextBlock does have this formatting capability.

Check out [this article](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/).

By applying the styles directly to the span, you'll get it persisted in the text box.

Excerpt:

```
                     TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                    tb.Inlines.Add("An example on ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("the TextBlock control ") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
                    tb.Inlines.Add("using ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("inline ") { FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic });
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("text formatting ") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
                    tb.Inlines.Add("from ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Code-Behind") { TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline });
                    tb.Inlines.Add(".");
```

**Update**
Got your update, but you can take the fonts and styles from the paragraph, and then apply them directly. At least it seems so from your sample above.

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.FontSize = 25;
para.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("new paragraph"));

Span span = new Span(para.ContentStart, para.ContentEnd);
span.FontWeight = para.FontWeight;
span.FontSize = para.FontSize;

tb.Inlines.Add(span);
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I can't apply styles directly, please see my update above.

Comment: See my update above - you can take the styles from the paragraph, and still applying them directly, in code.

Comment: The formatting of the paragraph can be anything and must not always refer to the whole span, so, unfortunately, I can't do this. Please see my Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TextBlock you can use [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and achieve the necessary formatting
Here is a sample code

```
// Create a formatted paragraph
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.FontSize = 25;
        para.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        para.Inlines.Add(new Run("Text of paragraph."));

        Myrichtextboxtbx.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
```

and then add your richtextbox to xaml

Comment: Please see my Update 2 above.